# Combining nested arrays into a single array with unique items

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

Suppose I have an object like this:

```
 hex_ids = [
    ["8d267451c3858ff", "8d267451c385bbf", "8d267451c385b3f", "8d267451c385b7f", "8d267451c3ae6bf", "8d267451c3ae6ff", "8d267451c3ae67f", "8d267451c3aa93f"], 
    ["8d267451c3aa93f", "8d267451c3ae2ff", "8d267451c3ae27f", "8d267451c3a8cbf", "8d267451c3a8dbf", "8d267451c3a8d3f", "8d267451c3ac6ff"]
 ]
```

The array has 2 nested array, each with a different length. At least one item in each nested array also exists in the other. What I want to do is combine these 2 nested arrays into a single array with unique items and eliminate any redundancies like this:

```
hex_ids = ["8d267451c3858ff", "8d267451c385bbf", "8d267451c385b3f", "8d267451c385b7f",
"8d267451c3ae6bf", "8d267451c3ae6ff", "8d267451c3ae67f", "8d267451c3aa93f", "8d267451c3ae2ff", 
"8d267451c3ae27f", "8d267451c3a8cbf", "8d267451c3a8dbf", "8d267451c3a8d3f", "8d267451c3ac6ff"]
```

What is the easiest method to do this?

Comment: `const newArray = Array.from(new Set(hex_ids.flatMap(item => item)))`

Comment: @secan - No reason to use `flatMap`, we have `flat`, avoiding the callback.

Comment: ... actualy using `flatMap()` is pointless when a simple `flat()` would do, as you can see in the answer from @Spectric

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yep, I realized it when I saw the answer from Spectric but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flatten the array with [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and get the unique values:

```js
const array = [
    ["8d267451c3858ff", "8d267451c385bbf", "8d267451c385b3f", "8d267451c385b7f", "8d267451c3ae6bf", "8d267451c3ae6ff", "8d267451c3ae67f", "8d267451c3aa93f"], 
    ["8d267451c3aa93f", "8d267451c3ae2ff", "8d267451c3ae27f", "8d267451c3a8cbf", "8d267451c3a8dbf", "8d267451c3a8d3f", "8d267451c3ac6ff"]
 ]
const result = [...new Set(array.flat())];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, that worked great! Literally the simplest and cleanest solution and I can't believe I've never seen .flat before.

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr=[];

for(let i of hex_ids){
 arr=arr.concat(i)
}
console.log(Array.from(new Set(arr)))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to elaborate on your answer and tell the OP and future readers, why, your particular solution works.